# Wine Selection Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

So this is quite a famous example of implementing DP but for some reason I can't completely understand the algorithm, and I've been stuck on it for quite some time(preparing for computing olympiad).The problem is as follows

> Imagine you have a collection of N wines placed next to each other on
>   a shelf. For simplicity, let's number the wines from left to right as
>   they are standing on the shelf with integers from 1 to N,
>   respectively. The price of the i-th wine is pi (prices of different
>   wines can be different).
>
> Because the wines get better every year, supposing today is the year
>   1, on year y the price of the i-th wine will be y*pi, i.e. y-times the
>   value that current year.
>
> You want to sell all the wines you have, but you want to sell exactly
>   one wine per year, starting on this year. One more constraint - on
>   each year you are allowed to sell only either the leftmost or the
>   rightmost wine on the shelf and you are not allowed to reorder the
>   wines on the shelf (i.e. they must stay in the same order as they are
>   in the beginning).
>
> You want to find out, what is the maximum profit you can get, if you
>   sell the wines in optimal order

And the solution in c++ is given(There is a solution with memoization but that hardly matters for my doubt):

```
int p[N]; // read-only array of wine prices


// year represents the current year (starts with 1)
// [be, en] represents the interval of the unsold wines on the shelf
int profit(int year, int be, int en) {
  // there are no more wines on the shelf
  if (be > en)
    return 0;
  // try to sell the leftmost or the rightmost wine, recursively calculate the 
  // answer and return the better one
  return max(
    profit(year+1, be+1, en) + year * p[be],
    profit(year+1, be, en-1) + year * p[en]);
}
```

The main confusion I have is related to the max() function we are using.As far as I can understand , the recursive profit() function calculates what would be the total profit if we sold wine 1 in the last year and what would be the total profit if we sold wine 2 in the last year.So lets say Wine 1 has the bigger total profit , if it is sold in the later years , so shouldn't we actually keep wine 1 (because it will fetch us more profit later on) and sell wine 2( as it would fetch a profit less than wine 1) , or is there something I am not getting?

Comment: "There is a solution with memoization but that hardly matters for my doubt" um, dynamic programming is a kind of memoization; if you skip that it is just an insanely inefficient algorithm.

Comment: @Yakk OP has no problem with DP in itself, but in how to get the recursion formula for this problem. Hence he is right when saying the memoization doesn't matter for his specific question.

Answer (score 1):

This recursive solution is that just check all possible scenerios and returning max of it. Here is an toy analysis, 2 possible condition pick rightmost or leftmost. Everystep, you can choose one of them so your algorithm works at O(2^n) which is really slow. max() is here to just select bigger one, nothing is special. And this solution is not dynamic, you can use memoization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization.

```
return max( 
profit(year+1, be+1, en) + year * p[be],
 profit(year+1, be, en-1) + year * p[en]);
```

it could be written like that also.

```
int max_from_left = profit(year+1, be+1, en) + year * p[be]

int max_from_right = profit(year+1, be, en-1) + year * p[en]);

if( max_from_left  >  max_from_right)
    return max_from_left
else 
    return max_from_right
```

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I can understand , the recursive profit() function calculates what would be the total profit if we sold wine 1 in the last year and what would be the total profit if we sold wine 2 in the last year.So lets say Wine 1 has the bigger total profit , if it is sold in the later years , so shouldn't we actually keep wine 1 (because it will fetch us more profit later on) and sell wine 2( as it would fetch a profit less than wine 1)

no its totally wrong, its a recursive algorithm it calculate what happen if sell wine 1 in year 1 or wine "last" in year one, imagine u have 10 wine max() will calculate for next  10 year and return answer